# Spitting long column values to managable size for presenting data neatly

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Hi I was wondering if there is a way to split long column values in this case I am using SSRS to get the distinct values with the number of product ID against a category into a matrix/pivot table in SSRS. The problem lies with the amount of distinct category makes it a nightmare to make the report look pretty shall we say. Is there a dynamic way to split the columns in say groups of 10 to make the table look nicer and easy to read. I was thinking of using in operator then the list of values but that means managing the data every time a new category gets added. Is there a dynamic way to present the data in the best way possible? There are 135 distinct category values

Also I am open to suggestions to make the report to nicer if anyone has any thoughts. I am new to SSRS and trying to get to grips with its.

Here is an example of my problem

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNTkB.jpg)

Comment: Can you give some examples? I use SSRS a lot and have had to do similar prettying, so I may be able to help.

Comment: Hi Lynn,I have provided the example in the main post with the image. The Column goes on forever it seems like with  125 distinct column value. Just want to find a way to put it into groups of say like 10 and have it one below the other rather then the user scrolling forever. Thank yu.

Comment: Trying to think how best to approach this.  I have some ideas, but need a little more context.  You have a dataset in SSRS with all these columns?

Comment: Is it appropriate for these to appear as columns as opposed to rows?  Especially if there is only a single value for each column?

Comment: Hiya, yes the data is one dataset and looks like this: 
SELECT       distinct prcIncidentManagement.SubCategory as Subcat,
  count(eFolder.eFolderName) as LogNo
   
FROM
  eUser  eUser2 RIGHT OUTER JOIN prcIncidentManagement ON (eUser2.eUserName=prcIncidentManagement.AssignedTo)
   INNER JOIN eFolder ON (prcIncidentManagement.EFOLDERID=eFolder.eFolderID)

 
group by   

--prcIncidentManagement.CallCategory,
prcIncidentManagement.SubCategory

Comment: It isn't an issue whether its in rows or columns, as long as the data can  be seen easily without the need of scrolling up/down or side to side

Comment: Another question - how possible is it to change the underlying data that is returned.  I think I have a solution if you can change the format of the data coming in (so the Field names are returned also)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that Jonnus, the data itself is from a service desk application where we have select access only. I maynot be able to change any underlying data. Were you thinking of grouping the data into similar types using a 'Like' clause then reducing the number of columns or rows?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this:
[image]

The following gives the steps (in two columns, down then across)

[image]

Comment: Yes that sort of format with the category section having all 125 distinct values listed in similar fashion rather than the usual columns or rows setup. Would that be possible to do in SQL or SSRS like the above?

Comment: That was done in SSRS. I'll add some details on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Are your column names coming back from the database under the SubCat field you note in the comments above?  If so I imagine your dataset looks something like this

```
Subcat   |     Logno
---------+---------------
SubCatA  |       34
SubCatB  |       65
SubCatC  |       120
SubCatD  |       8
SubCatE  |       19
```

You can edit this so that there is an index of each individual category being returned also, using the Row_Number() function.  Add the field

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SubCat ASC) AS ColID
```

To your query.  This will result in the following.

```
Subcat     |     LogNo    |   ColID
-----------+--------------+----------
SubCatA    |       34     |     1
SubCatB    |       65     |     2
SubCatC    |       120    |     3
SubCatD    |       8      |     4
SubCatE    |       19     |     5
```

Now there is a numeric identifier for each column you can perform some logic on it to arrange itself nicely on the page.

This solution involves a Tablix, nested inside a Matrix nested inside a Matrix as follows

[image]

First create a Matrix (Matrix1), and set it’s datasource to your dataset.  Set the Row Group Properties to group on the following expression where ‘4’ is the number of columns you wish to display horizontally.

```
=CInt(Floor((Fields!ColID.Value - 1) / 4))
```

[image]

Then in the data section of the Matrix (bottom right corner) insert a rectangle and on this insert a new Matrix (Matrix 2).  Remove the leftmost row. Set the column header to be the Column Name SubCat.  This will automatically set the column grouping to be SubCat.

[image]

Finally, in the Data Section of Matrix 2 add a new Rectangle and Add a Tablix on it.  Remove the Header Row, and set it to be one column wide only.  Set the Data to be the information you wish to display, i.e. LogNo.

Finally, delete the Leftmost and Topmost rows/columns from Matrix 1 to make it look tidier (Note Delete Column Row only! Not associated groups!)

Then when the report is run it should look similar to the following.  Note in my example SubCat = ColName, and LogNo = NumItems, and I have multiple values per SubCat.

[image]

Hopefully you find this helpful.  If not, please ask for clarification.

Comment: HI Jonnus, I am having issues displaying this properly, if you can refer to my main post I have copied the link. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding that new image you have posted - can you explain where you are with the solution?  You have 2 ells with data shown in them when my example above only has 2 for example...?

Comment: Also, I have just seen your comment about not being able to edit the underlying dataset.  Does this mean you'd like help to determine the unique row number within SSRS only?

Comment: I have added the unique row ID in the sql and copied this into the dataset which is perfect. I am now trying to get this to work in SSRS where the matrix is within the matrix and table. The output is on the main post to the link of how this looks like. Regards to the output when you preview the report it just has empty cells which means I have done something wrong no doubt. Possibly at the point when you insert rectangle does it remove the row you highlight? I had to add another row then insert rectangle in that fashion to get it looking similar to yours. But without any success :(

Comment: I agree, if the preview is blank it implies something has gone wrong somewhere.  Your new image in the main post above shows data in 4 places ([cat],[cat],[Sun(LogNo)],[LogNo]).  I would have thought that only the second [cat] and [LogNo] were required.  It's difficult to tell in your image what is what (Matrix/Tablix etc.).  are you above to add further description to that image?